# Why am I getting pixelated videos in FFmpeg when converting to a GIF?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, gif

I want to encode this WEBM video:

- https://buggem.github.io/connecting.webm

I have been noticing the fact that FFmpeg has been played up when it comes to quality.

I am doing WEBM to GIF, if that helps. And almost all online converters use FFmpeg under the hood, resulting in that same loss in quality.

Notice that the first frame on the FFmpeg encoding is very pixelated:

[image]

Here is the command I have been using for the encoding.

```shell
ffmpeg -i connecting.webm -vf "fps=40,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 output.gif
```

Even if I convert the WEBM source to a MP4 instead of a GIF the quality loss remains.

And I had to add the `-vf` option to fix the bugged frame rate. The bugged conversion is down below.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you saying you are “doing WEMB to GIF” but your source video is an MP4?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y67yX.gif) is the output of `ffmpeg -y -i 5e99c316d45acb7c38e9.mp4 -vf "fps=40,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 output.gif`. It could be an FFmpeg version issue, but it could also be that the WebM file has transparency. Try `palettegen=reserve_transparent=1`. Try to share the original WebM input file.

Comment: @Rotem issue with the file itself?? Or the WEBM encoder? Will add to question

Comment: @Rotem added to question

Comment: maybe, scale flag lanczos. compare: `ffmpeg -i connecting.webm -vf "
split[a][b];
[a]scale=320:-1,split[a][c];
[b]scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[b][d];
[a][b]blend=all_mode=difference[e];
[c][e][d]hstack=3
" -frames:v 1 /tmp/1.png`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов not sure what y mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original WebM input file has an alpha (transparency) channel.
Possible solution is overlaying the semi-transparent video over a black background:

`ffmpeg -y -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i connecting.webm -vf "[v:0]fps=40[v0];color=black:rate=40[b];[b][v0]scale2ref[b][v0];[b]setsar=1[b];[b][v0]overlay=shortest=1,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 output.gif`

When ignoring the alpha the videos is pixelated, because the smoothness is created by gradual change of the transparency around the object.

---

- `-c:v libvpx-vp9` - Use `libvpx-vp9` decoder. We need it because the default decoder ignores the alpha (transparency) channel.
- `color=black:rate=40[b]` - Creates a black video with at 40fps with some nominal resolution.
- `[b][v0]scale2ref[b][v0]` - Scales the black video to the resolution of the input video.
- `[b]setsar=1[b]` - Set the aspect ratio of the black video to 1:1.
- `[b][v0]overlay=shortest=1` - overlays the input video over the black video.
- `scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse"` - scale generate palette and use it, as in the question.

---

Output:
[image]

---

Remarks about the alpha (transparency) channel of the input:

When executing `ffprobe connecting.webm`, it shows:

```
  Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 400x400, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libvpx-vp9
      DURATION        : 00:00:01.067000000
```

The `alpha_mode : 1` Metadata marks that there is a alpha (transparency) channel.

I think it is some kind of "special" configuration (normally I would expect pixel format to be yuva420p and not yuv420p when there is an alpha channel).
There is some documentation about the `alpha_mode : 1` related to [VP8 encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8#AlphaChannel).